# Doctor Who radio programme. Heard 1998. Scientist has transferred consciousness of his entire race into immortal robot bodies

Tags: story-identification, robots, immortality, radio-play

I listened to the end of this show in 1998 or 1999. I don't know if it was a repeat. I am pretty sure it was supposed to be Tom Baker's doctor. I don't know if it was Tom Baker. It was on BBC Radio 2 or possibly Radio 4.

The scientist has helped all his people achieve immortality by transferring their consciousness into everlasting robot bodies.

> He finds out at the end. The transfer failed. He murdered all his people when he burned the 'empty' flesh bodies.

I checked out the summary of the Blake's 7 radio shows broadcast in 1998 but the stories do not match.

Comment: I'm almost sure I heard something like this story described recently, and I just CANNOT remember it! Are you sure it wasn't Radio 4, btw?

Comment: I am not completely certain. It was a while ago.

Comment: Do you remember roughly when in 1998 this was? Autumn? Winter? Other?

Comment: I think it was light in the early evening. Possibly it was Spring/ Summer it ia also possible i was 99.

Comment: It reminds me a bit of "Rights" from [the first Short Trips collection](http://www.drwhoguide.com/whotrip1.htm) - but that wasn't one of the stories converted into audio format. Still, it did have the Fourth Doctor in.

Comment: I remember the kitchen of the house I was listening to it in. I only lived there for one year.

Comment: Could it possibly have been a cassette tape or CD, as opposed to a radio broadcast?

Comment: No it was only a radio in the room.

Comment: I read about Rights. I do not thiink this is it. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: Which part of the UK were you living in? Could this have been some local radio station that wasn't part of the BBC?

Comment: I was living in Greater Manchester. I

Comment: *"I checked out the summary of the Blake's 7 radio shows broadcast in 1998 but the stories do not match."*. Luckily, because you mentioned it might have been 1999 - I've [found it](https://blakes7.fandom.com/wiki/The_Syndeton_Experiment_(audio))

Comment: Given the edits made after the question was answered... it might be worth removing the [doctor-who] tag and substituting a [blakes-7] tag?

Comment: Good idea, thanks.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern - Our stated policy is that [we don't edit Story-ID questions based on the answers that they get](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13471/should-i-correct-misremembered-details-in-my-question?noredirect=1&lq=1). In this instance I've rolled back the changes.

Comment: @Valorum I'm aware, but the context here was that the OP had already made those edits, and this had resulted in a question about Blake's 7 that was tagged as a Doctor Who question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a Blake's 7 audio drama called [*The Syndeton Experiment*](https://blakes7.fandom.com/wiki/The_Syndeton_Experiment_(audio)), broadcast in April 1999.

From the linked wiki page:

> When they finally locate Dr. Rossum he's an elderly man with a weak heart who has become insane, believing himself to be a saviour. He has been transferring the minds of the populace into "nanobots", three-armed, three-legged purple androids with superior mental capacity. His ultimate aim is to place himself in control of them all, in a chief nanobot. ... Avon tells Rossum that his ideas were incorrect, and the "minds" he transferred to his nanobots were only copies, the "dead" bodies he burnt still alive. Realising he has committed genocide and unwittingly murdered nearly two million people, Rossum dies, leaving the Scorpio crew to take off, pondering whether or not Servalan is still alive...

> The Syndeton Experiment was ... broadcast on BBC Radio 4 as part of their The Saturday Play slot. It was originally scheduled for 19/12/1998, explaining why you might see this date listed as its original broadcast date in some listings out there.

Sadly, Tom Baker was not one of the cast members.

Comment: "Rossum". Nice nod to Karel Čapek.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern Awesome find considering I had misremembered Blake's 7 as Doctor Who. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: @JudithJones You're welcome!